# Accessing SQL server residing on AWS through application on local machine

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

I have SQL server 208 R2 hosted on AWS. Can I access that SQL server through my web application on local machine without VPN?

What connection string we need to give in web.config. So I no need to have SQL server on my local machine.

I can run and test my application without having SQL server on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL Server is publicly accessible, then you can simply connect directly to it. It's a bad practice to expose database servers directly to the internet, however, so don't do this.

If your SQL Server is *not* publicly accessible, then you can connect to it via an SSH tunnel. You would launch a publicly-accessible EC2 instance, restrict its security groups to allowing SSH from your local IP address, and then use SSH on your local machine to port-forward to the SQL Server via the SSH tunnel. You can then connect your database client to the local port on your machine and that will be forwarded to the SQL server via the SSH tunnel. Here's an [example](https://userify.com/blog/howto-connect-mysql-ec2-ssh-tunnel-rds/).

The SQL Server will also have to allow inbound connections from your EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's the default SQL Server instance listening on port 443, and your EC2 instance has a public IP address, you could do the following:

1. Enable access to your EC2 instance through port 443 from your local machine public IP.
2. Configure Windows firewall to allow access through port 443
3. Ensure TCP/IP protocol is enabled for your SQL Server Instance
4. Use data `source=<the public ip address of your E2 instance>` in the connection string.

To enable access to your EC2 instance through port 443 from your local machine public IP do the following:

1. Go to AWS mangement console.
2. Go to EC2 Service.
3. Click on Running Instances
4. Click on your EC2 instance running SQL Server
5. Click on one of the security groups listed on the Description tab.
6. Click on the Inbound tab.
7. Click on the Edit button
8. Click on Add Rule button
9. Select Custom TCP rule on the Type dropdown list.
10. Enter 443 on Port Range.
11. Select My IP on Source dropdown list.
12. Enter "SQL Server from My local IP" on Description text box.

Your public IP address might change over time, so you might need to update the source when this happens.

To configure Windows firewall to allow access through port 443 open an RDP session to your EC2 instance and use Windows Firewall with Advanced Security tool and add the the rule.

To ensure TCP/IP protocol is enabled for your SQL Server Instance do the following:

1. Open an Remote Desktop session to your EC2 instance.
2. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager.
3. Expand SQL Server Network Configuration
4. Click on Protocols for
5. Enable TCP/IP protocol if not enabled.

Hope it helps